# Отслеживать открытия письма

Tags: php

Есть скрипт который генерирует HTML письма с с пикселем, почтовые сервера пропускают img через свой прокси и соответственно у меня в скрипте, засчитывается открытие, не человеком. Какие еще есть способы отследить открытие письма?

Comment: Возможно находили, но всё же. [Ссылка](https://toster.ru/q/297568).

Comment: Да проходил по этой ссылке

Answer (score 0):

Добавить ссылку на изображение в html разметку письма - 1х1 прозрачное и с дополнительными GET-параметрами.
Как увидите переход по ссылке с этим параметром - засчитывайте открытие.
Способ более-менее точный.

Comment: Ест у меня ссылка она подсчитывать статистику переходов мне надо именно открытия считать

Comment: Я использую Unisender для таких случаев.

Comment: А что делать если почтовики заменяют мою картинка на дубликат со своего сервера?